# Watermarking videos in batch

Tags: windows, video, video-editing, digital-watermarking

I need **video editing software** for **Windows** that can process up to 10 videos in batch. 
I just need to add watermarks to several videos (8-10).

I need a software where I can add a bunch of video files, then add watermarks on each of them, then click and wait till all the videos are processed. I don't want to edit each of the videos individually so that I need to add videos consequently and wait till each of the videos is processed and do the same with all the video files and repeat it again and again.

I need this editor to be able to process different video formats: `mpeg4`, `avi`, `wmv`, `mkv`.

It does not matter if the software is free or paid.

*Note: also I need software that process videos without quality loss, so that it is not deteriorated after adding watermarks.*

Actually it doesn't have to be literally parallel. I just don't want to repeat same actions for all the videos. I want to somehow automate the process of adding watermarks for several videos.

---

Is there such software that can help in such task?

**Upd:** I'm more interested in traditional software than web services, videos are quite heavy and I can't upload all the videos then download back from website all videos. It will take too much time.

Comment: It will be better if such software will allow adding not only watermarks but some text and labels also.

Answer (score 1):

[FormatFactory](http://www.pcfreetime.com/formatfactory/index.php?language=en) will allow you to add watermark to a video. It's free to download and use and it's actually quite good as it can do a lot of conversions on music, video and image files among others.

For watermark, it will accept any jpg,bmp or png image files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not a "software" in the traditional sense, but **[www.watermark.ws](http://www.watermark.ws)** does an awesome job with things like this!

It can add an image or text. Has a free base version with a paid upgrade for more freedom and features.